# Get generic type in Async callback

Tags: c#, .net, generics, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

I'm writing a library that communicates with a JsonRpc service via HTTP. All HTTP operations are done async by design.

Each command sent to the JsonRpc service will result in the server responding with a list of items.

The process is user calls GetXXXX method and provides a callback (Very cut down version):

```
GetArtists(userCallback)
{
   var state = new AsyncState<Artist>(userCallback);

   jsonRpcClient.post(uri, internalCallback, AsyncState);
}


GetArtistsInternalCallback(httpStatusCode, responseBody, asyncState)
{
    var realState = asyncState as AsyncState<Artist>.


   // parse response body in to list of Artists


   realState.UserCallback(List<Artist>);
}


UserCallback(List<Artist> artists)
{
   User can do something with result
}
```

Now the Async state is generic, so if I had a method called GetAlbums for example the user would supply a callback with a signature of UserCallback(List albums) etc.

This is working fine but now what I want to do is make the InternalCallback generic. I have a lot of GetXXXX methods to implement and they all follow the exact same pattern.

I want my AsyncState to have a delegate on it that processes the server response so the InternalCallback would look something like:

```
InternalCallback(httpStatusCode, responseBody, asyncState)
{
    var realState = asyncState as AsyncState<MAGICALLY-FIGURE-OUT-TYPE>.

    *Do generic work here*

     var listOfItems = asyncState.ProcessServerResponse(responseBody)

     realState.UserCallback(List<MAGIC-TYPE> listOfItems);
}
```

So this would allow me to stop repeating the InternalCallback for every GetXXX method (Only thing that changes is the type).

But I now have the problem of how do I figure out the type of the state object in the callback? Up until now it's explicitly declared i.e. GetArtistsInternalCallback knows it's working with Artists but if I had a generic callback how would it figure out the type?

EDIT: Also if it makes any difference the Artist and Album types are derived from a common base class called MediaItem.

Cheers,

Tyler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the somewhat pseudo-code presented, but is there any reason you couldn't just make InternalCallback a generic method, and supply the type argument when you create the callback delegate instance?

The method can be generic even though the delegate isn't. Here's an example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    delegate void Callback(object o);

    static void Main()
    {
        Callback callback = ShowType<int>;
        callback(10);
    }

    static void ShowType<T>(object value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + value);
        Console.WriteLine("typeof(T) = " + typeof(T));
        Console.WriteLine("value.GetType() = " + value.GetType());
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to specify the right type when you create the callback, but it sounds like this wouldn't be a problem in your situation.

Comment: I could... But the InternalCallback delegate is actually an HttpResponseReceived delegate on my HttpClient - So I'd rather not modify that with code that's specific to this situation.

Comment: @Tyler: I'm not suggesting you change the *delegate*. I'm suggesting you change the *method* used to create a delegate instance.

Comment: Thank you so much I never knew you could add generics to a method on an adhoc basis even if the delegate isn't generic. Works perfectly :)

Comment: @Tyler: Excellent - glad I hadn't misunderstood the requirements :)